# Writing bytes to file, bad encoding

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x

I have a problem in Python 3.x with writing to file, write function in FOR is writing czech signs in utf-8 coding.
I am new in Python but i set up IDE and .py, .xml files for 'utf-8' encoding and i have no idea why is output file looking like that.
My code:

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
from io import BytesIO
import sys
import codecs

f = open('uzivatelska_prirucka.xml','rb')
fo = open('try.xml','wb',1)

header = '?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<root\n'
fo.write(bytes(header,'UTF-8'))

some_file_like_object = f
tree = etree.parse(some_file_like_object)
root = tree.getroot() 
node = tree.xpath('/prirucka/body/p');

for a in node:
    for b in a.getiterator():
        if not (b.find('r') is None): 
            text = etree.tostring(b.find('r'))
            fo.write(bytes(str(text),'UTF-8'))
```

Thanks for your help and advices

Comment: Perhaps write a proper opening bracket...

Comment: The `open` function in python3. has an `encoding` parameter that you can use to avoid those explicit conversions.

Comment: f = open('uzivatelska_prirucka.xml','rb',encoding='utf-8'), there is an error: Binary mode does not take an encoding argument

Comment: You must open it in text mode, to znamená pouze `'r'`, and not `'rb'`. There is probably no need to use `codecs` module here in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary to read and write in binary mode??
I think a XML file is a simple text file and you could use it just like a txt file
also you should know python3.2 and newer versions of python don't make any difference between ASCII and UTF strings
python3.2 and above see all strings as unicode strings so you can write your string in the output file whether the string contains non-ASCII characters or not
Also I find no need to open file in binary mode to use with `lxml.etree` package

Try to open files in text mode ( get rid of that `b` in opening mode ) and see if it works but keep in mind tell open to use `utf-8` encoding to open your files

```
f = open('uzivatelska_prirucka.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
fo = open('try.xml', 'w', 1, encoding='utf-8')
```

As a side note, you could just write:

```
if b.find('r'):
```

instead of:

```
if not (b.find('r') is None):
```

because `None` in if clauses assumed as `False` and if `find()` returns `None` python itself don't run the code in if block and jump it:

```
$ python3.3
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(1) if None else print(0)
0
>>> print(1) if not None else print(0)
1
```

Have fun coding ;)

Comment: Ou yeah that`s it. But i have problem with writing lxml object to the file. (etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True)) return type bytes and encoding is bad in file. Is there some alternative without lxml ?

Comment: Solved. I used xml.etree.ElementTree